# QFieldSync Python Error

Tags: qgis, windows

QGIS version 3.28.5-Firenze

Python version 3.9.5

When configuring layers of my QGIS project, I get the following error (user in file path replaced with "xxx" for security):

> 2023-05-30T14:34:35     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\layers_config_widget.py",
> line 93, in
> lambda msg: self._on_message_bus_messaged(msg)
> File "C:\Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\layers_config_widget.py",
> line 274, in _on_message_bus_messaged
> layer_source.read_layer()
> File "C:\Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync\layer.py",
> line 122, in read_layer
> self._action = self.layer.customProperty("QFieldSync/action")
> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted

I previously received this message using QGIS 3.22. My solution was to upgrade to 3.28. But now after 2 months or so of using 3.28, this error message is suddenly appearing again. I have made no changes to my system.

Can someone advise what is causing this and how to resolve it?

EDIT
+++++++
Post title changed to be more specific.
After bugmenot123's comment, I re-installed QFieldYnc plugin. All now working.
ON re-installing

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the qfieldsync plugin, please file a bug and/or check if there is a new version available already.